# How am I supposed to use a standard flag when Stack Overflow won't let me?

Tags: discussion

Nearly four weeks ago I flagged a post as being off-topic/low-quality because it's quite literally a copy-paste of an error message and no effort is shown to understand the error message whatsoever. However, it "aged away", so now I can't report it again:

[image]

So, instead my only option was to select "in need of moderator intervention", explain the issue, and I even stated that I couldn't raise a standard flag. And *yet*, it was declined, *and I was told to use a standard flag*!

[image]

Where is the logic in this? How can I be expected to use a standard flag when I can't use a standard flag?

Link to the post: [Requirement.parse('six>=1.6.0') version about python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42171851/3150837)

Comment: Link to the post? Then we can at least handle it, if necessary

Comment: @Bart Sorry, should've added that in. Done.

Comment: Wait, so it should definitely be closed up to a point where you poke a mode to do it, but you answered it anyway? Which one is it? Either it should be closed, or it's answerable and should stay.

Comment: Well, since it's there, I answered it, but to me it doesn't really look like a good question for the site regardless.

Comment: @Bart I found a dupe, let's at least close it against that

Comment: Well, you gave it your best shot, it didn't work.  Deleting content is pretty hard, it gets about impossible on old content like this.  Do beware you make it extra hard by having an answer on it.  A moderator can do it, but they rarely delete stuff like this.  "I have an error" questions tend to get a lot of google hits.  Not this one, it is too lazy and can't get indexed until the error message is edited into the question body.  Gathering a posse to tar and feather it sometimes works, a chat room is the usual vehicle, you just did.

Comment: There are two problems here: the first is that there's apparently a bug that [recurred](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266501/cant-re-flag-aged-away-flag) around flag aging, and the second is that a mod didn't read your flag to realize that you were working around a site bug.